# Stack Overflow continually asking for cookie permission

Tags: bug, login, cookies

Since yesterday, Stack Overflow asks for accepting cookies every time the page is reloaded. Example: I'm going to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash and I click on "Accept all cookies" (which makes the cookie dialogue disappear) and then reload the page (or follow a  link to another Stack Overflow page), I am again requested to accept the cookies.

This does not happen on meta.stackexchange.com, on superuser.com or serverfault.com. It seems to be particular to Stack Overflow.

This happens on Firefox 112.0.1 under Windows which I normally use.

I also tried it on Chrome (version 74.0.3729.131), but the behaviour with Chrome is even worse: Even if I click on "Accept all cookies", the cookie dialogue does not go away and therefore I can't even login to the site with Chrome.

At least for Firefox, disabling the Firefox add-on "DuckDuckGo Privacy Essentials" solved the problem for me. Note: Just whitelisting stackoverflow.com in AdBlock Plus was not sufficient.

As for Chrome, I don't have any plugins installed.